# SQL Server 2012 Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have records in SQL Server 2012 Table

[image]

Need a SQL Select statement, that can only pull EmpID 1202, 1203 only since these records has EndDate. The 1201, has one record that has Null value (Empty), so it means the person has current medical plan. so need to skip both records completely. Please advise and thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: If you don't know how to do a select statement, I suggest you don't touch the database.  Get someone who knows database to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention what I tried so far but Ruben's answer helps. Thank you!

Comment: If Ruben's answer did the trick for you than you should accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a subselect to isolate the users with medical plan and exclude them with the `NOT IN` clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmpID FROM [Table]
WHERE  EmpID NOT IN
(
       SELECT EmpID FROM [Table]
       WHERE  EndDate IS NULL
)
```

Comment: That will not work. 
The EmpID will join to some records,when there is both a null and not null record..

Comment: Try it, @Newport99 ;)

Comment: Sure enough. Damn dyslexia.

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer apply. In my case I only want 302 and 349 as the other dealers have a record with a null invoice date.

[image]